# How to read the version timestamp of ActiveRecord::Schema.define?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

When I see the version value in in schema.rb of a Rails 4.2 application as below, it looks like 2015 is the year, 04 is the month (April), and 27 is the day.  But what is 115639 then?

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150427115639) do
```

I'm trying to understand how the ActiveRecord::Schema version value is formatted.

It's not a Unix timestamp is it?  If I convert a particular day month time as follows using an online calculator I get:

```
1429927200

Is equivalent to:

04/25/2015 @ 2:00am (UTC)
```

which doesn't seem to match the value defined by version.

Mostly I'm trying to understand how to quickly decide if a merge contains a more updated schema version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema version comes from the timestamp of the most recent migration. That in turn is the concatenated digits of the date and time when the migration was generated. `20150427115639` comes from "2015-04-27 11:56:39".